# How to convert JSON to Excel but do not download the file in Angular 14

Tags: json, angular, excel

I am trying to convert a JSON object into an Excel file in memory and then pass that file into another method to render it on screen using a third party library. I know how to download the file, but in this case I want to store the file in a variable and then pass it into another method to use. Is there a way to do that using Angular 14?

Comment: Can you show some of the code you wrote so far?